# turn jQuery object/code into a plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, plugins, jquery-plugins

So I have read through a few tutorials, and I am still confused how to turn my specific tagging system into a usable plugin.

I have the following object declared with a bunch of functions as such:

```
var Tags = {};

Tags.Class = function() {
  ...
};
```

Then I declare the prototype:

```
Tags.TaggingForm = new Tags.Class();

// Only takes text input fields for now!
Tags.TaggingForm.prototype = {
    initialize: function(tag_field){
       ...
    },
    hideInputField: function() {
      ...
    },
```

Then I have the actual function call that using that object:

```
Tags.make_tagging_input = function (id) {

var

 tagger = new Tags.TaggingForm(id);
...
 }
```

I am just wondering how I can turn this into a plugin: current I call it as such:

```
window.g_gloab_var = Tags.make_tagging_input("#id");
```

This skeleton keeps being suggested, but I am not sure how to apply it:

```
//You need an anonymous function to wrap around your function to avoid conflict
```

(function($){

```
//Attach this new method to jQuery
$.fn.extend({ 

    //This is where you write your plugin's name
    tags_input: function() {

        //Iterate over the current set of matched elements
        return this.each(function() {

            //code to be inserted here

        });
        }
    });

//pass jQuery to the function, 
//So that we will able to use any valid Javascript variable name 
//to replace "$" SIGN. But, we'll stick to $ (I like dollar sign: ) )       
})(jQuery);
```

Comment: Have you try using `this` to get the element you want to work on? You can put your original code in the plugin file, and in the most inner function, run your code on `this`.

Answer (score 0):

Don't have the time to go to into depth on this right now but my favorite boilerplate for plugin creation is [Stefan Gabos's](http://stefangabos.ro/jquery/jquery-plugin-boilerplate-oop/)

Good comments and pretty easy to follow. Hope that helps. I'll check back later when I have more time but hopefully this is helpful for now.

Answer (score 0):

Youu can use your original code and have a plugin like this:

```
(function($) {

// your original code here
$.fn.extend({ 

    tags_input: function(options) {

        //Iterate over the current set of matched elements
        // that we would call via $(selector).tags_input(options);
        // e.g. $('.tags_input').tags_input({a: true, b: "some string"});
        return this.each(function() {

            // call your plugin here,
            // options can be an object of parameters to the plugin

            // using your code and calling it on "this"
            // e.g. Tags.make_tagging_input("#" + this.id);

        });
        }
    });

})(jQuery);
```